# Rex begonia dropping young leaves

Tags: leaves, begonia

I have a rex begonia (escargot variety) that was just moved to a new location in the house (from a sunny window to under a lit shelf).

I've noticed that it has started to drop very young leaves after the leaf and ~1/2 of the stem turn brown and shrivel.

Is this anything to be concerned about? I would like it to continue growing -- is there a way to encourage the leaves to stay?

---

It is watered once every 3-4 days (when beginning to wilt), lives in light soil, under medium artificial light, in 70-80F temperatures and medium humidity.

---

A couple of photos as requested: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyh9b.jpg https://i.stack.imgur.com/04Ck9.jpg

Comment: What kind of light?  What is the wattage the type of bulb...what type of "light soil"...is it potting soil? The less light a plant gets from what it has gotten used to less water is necessary.  The plant won't use any more water than it needs.  Then it gets root rot.  I like how you are watering however.  Have you noticed that is doesn't 'wilt' since moving?  Yet you still water it like before when it had more light?  Moving a plant from one environment to another acclimation is necessary.  Otherwise the plant tries to adapt, very very stressful.  Put it back.  Cut off all dead stuff.

Comment: I would pop that plant out of its pot to take a look at the roots and the soil.  If that soil is mushy with water and has brown roots, you need to repot this plant into potting soil, only.  Or it might be too far gone to come back to health.  Please send a picture, what fertilizer, what soil have you used...?

Comment: Added some photos as requested.